the problem of connecting to a Python socket
I'm trying to make my telegram bot turn off the computer when I wrote 'off' to it. I don't want to connect the bot to the hosting on the site. I chose my phone (Android Redmi Note 10) for hosting. I installed Termux and Pydroid on it. I wrote two files: main to my computer and client to my phone. By running both files on the computer, everything worked. But when I run 'main' on the computer and 'client' on the phone it gives an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/downloads/FridayBeta.py", line4, in <module>
    client.connect(("adress"))
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

the 'main' file to run on the computer:
import socket
import os

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(('adress'))
server.listen()
while True:
    user, adres = server.accept()
    while True:
        data = user.recv(1024).decode("utf-8").lower()
        print(data)
        if data == "off":
            os.system('shutdown -s -t 0')

the "client" file to run on the phone:
import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(('adress'))

import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('my api')
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def hi(message):
    if message.text.lower == "off":
        client.send("off".encode("utf-8"))
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "hi")
        q = message.text.lower()
        client.send(q.encode("utf-8"))


while 5<6:
    bot.polling()

I tried to find an answer on the Internet, but it didn't work out

corrected, replaced with text.Please help me

It appears that the statement user, adres = server.accept() can only be executed once limiting your server to a single client connection for the lifetime of the server due to the inner while True: loop that never terminates. Any additional attempt by a client to connect will timeout. Also, as far as the statement while 5<6: is concerned, I ask, "Really?" Also, client.send("off".encode("utf-8")) -> client.send(b"off")

it didn't help either
